# Quota calculator for YouTube Analytics/Reporting APIs

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, quota, youtube-analytics-api

I found a calculator for YouTube Data API - https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost

But for my task I need a calculator for YouTube Analytics/Reporting APIs

Does such a calculator even exist?
OR does it mean that 1 request to Analytics/Reporting API equals 1 quota?

Any information on this would be appreciated
Thanks

I checked the documentation of YouTube Analytics/Reporting API but did not find any information
I found only https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota

Whether the request to Analytics/Reporting API is considered a read or a search operаtion?

Comment: The API server evaluates each query to determine its quota cost.  https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting